# type constructor: what does struct b(i32) in rust?

Tags: struct, rust

I know that in rust, I can define a type alias ("just another name") by

```rust
type n = i32;
```

and that I can create a new struct with one or multiple fields by

```rust
struct a {
    number: i32,
}
```

but I don't know what the third method does?

```rust
struct b(i32);
```

Comment: In the rust book: [Tuple structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html?highlight=tuple,struct#using-tuple-structs-without-named-fields-to-create-different-types)

Comment: Also, when tuple structs have just one element in the tuple, they're often referred to as [newtype](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-for-type-safety-and-abstraction) and serve as an abstraction rather than for data grouping, as is typically the case with tuple structs.